# Is Common Lisp available for 64 bit Power PC?

Tags: common-lisp

Is common lisp available for 64 bit PowerPC? I have tried to install Steel Bank Common Lisp (SBCL) on my 64 bit PowerPC system which is running Running hat linux, but since SBCL only supports 32 bit PowerPC, I need 32 bit libraries, which are problematic to get on Red Hat Linux, as it has minimal support for 32 bit on 64 bit Power PC. So, my question is, is there any common lisp available that can run directly on 64 bit Power PC?

Answer (score 2):

http://ccl.clozure.com

Clozure CL is available for the following platforms:

- Mac OS X 10.6 and later (x86, x86-64)
- **Linux** (x86, x86-64, ppc32, **ppc64**, armv7l/armv6)
- FreeBSD (x86, x86-64)
- Solaris (x86, x86-64)
- Microsoft Windows XP and later (x86, x86-64)

Comment: When I run it, I get the error "remap spjump: Invalid argument". Any idea what is goin on there?

Comment: @MetallicPriest: How about asking on the Clozure CL mailing list with a proper bug report?